# How to build a water lander that can move?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've build several landers that can safely splash down in water (on moons like Laythe, for instance). However, they cannot move around. The lander is basically a standard rover, with a lot of RCS. Unfortunately, RCS does nothing in water.

What kind of engines or tricks should I use to make a water rover?

Comment: Start looking for mods.

Comment: @MBraedley The idea is not to use mods, but construct the floating lander out of stock parts, specifically.

Comment: You can do it without mods, but it definitely isn't easy.  B9 and Hooligan Labs are really the way to go.

Comment: @polemon "not to use mods" - hardly possible at all, "splashed" status makes it really difficult. As you have already seen, it disables most modes of propulsion and you need to try to start and get airborne to be able to move again.

Answer (score 1):

[here is detailed a mission on laythe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TEIl.jpg)

it used a water tug to assemble station pieces.

check out

- the tug engine configuration and floating technique
- the individual base components floating technique